# Angular + jasmine test nested ViewChild components

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, viewchild

I have some problem with unit testing of `ionViewDidLeave` function on DashboardPage:

```js
@Component({
  template: '<app-dashboard-slider #dashboardSlider></app-dashboard-slider>',
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
})
export class DashboardPage {
  @ViewChild('dashboardSlider', { static: false }) dashboardSlider?: DashboardSliderComponent;

  ionViewDidLeave(): void {
    this.dashboardSlider?.swiper?.swiperRef.disable();
  }
}
```

The `DashboardSliderComponent` contain `SwiperComponent`

```js
@Component({
  template: '<swiper #swiper></swiper>',
  selector: 'app-dashboard-slider',
})
export class DashboardSliderComponent {
  @ViewChild('swiper', { static: false }) swiper?: SwiperComponent;
}
```

and I have no idea, how I can reach the `disable()` function with mocking

```js
// stub component
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard-slider',
    template: '',
  })
  class DashboardSliderStubComponent {
    swiper: SwiperComponent = {} as SwiperComponent;
  }


beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DashboardPage, DashboardSliderStubComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        // {
        //   provide: DashboardSliderComponent,
        //   useClass: DashboardSliderStubComponent,
        // },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    // populate childComponent with an instance of the stub
    component.dashboardSlider = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardSliderStubComponent).componentInstance as DashboardSliderComponent;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));


  fdescribe('Test ionViewDidLeave', () => {
    it('t1', () => {
      const swiperRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('swiperRef', ['disable'], ['autoplay']);

      spyOn<any>(component.dashboardSlider, 'swiper').and.returnValue({ swiperRef: swiperRefSpy });

      component.ionViewDidLeave();
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(swiperRefSpy.disable).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

currently, I have an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'disable')

Can you please help me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
spyOn<any>(component.dashboardSlider, 'swiper').and.returnValue({ swiperRef: swiperRefSpy });
```

since you can only `spyOn` public methods and `swiper` is an instance variable.

For a quick unblock, try mocking this property directly to have the properties you require and assign it to a spy:

```
let disableSpy: jasmine.Spy;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard-slider',
    template: '',
  })
  class DashboardSliderStubComponent {
    swiper: SwiperComponent = { swiperRef: { disable: disableSpy } as SwiperComponent;
  }

fdescribe('Test ionViewDidLeave', () => {
    it('t1', () => {

      component.ionViewDidLeave();
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(disableSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

To have a better understanding of testing in Angular, read this e-book: https://testing-angular.com/.